# POST then GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

is there a way I can make a POST request then immediately make a GET request afterwards? I need the POST request to finish completely before making the GET request...

Thank you.

Comment: Is that to return the data you just posted ? if so, you may consider the result of the post call to return the saved data, therefore, you don't need the second get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback for post in jQuery for making the second get request.

```
$.post( "your url", function( data ) {
  // Invoke your get method
});
```